# How is a fixed shower glass panel attached to a shower base?

Tags: shower, sliding-glass-door

I would like to have a setup like the one in the picture
I am not sure what is the standard practice to attach the panel to the shower base at the bottom. The picture shows a shower sit, imagine that that one is not there
Do they drill holes (I would hate that idea) ?

[image]

Comment: Why not go to a showroom and look at the various types? You're not intending to design your own, are you? A shower enclosure may look simple, but a fair amount of effort goes into engineering safety and water-tightness.

Comment: Because none of the stores I know of has that setup.

Comment: Though I've provided an answer, frankly this is too broad. I've answered about how _this_ one is attached, but there are many surrounds with many attachment methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence or absence of the shower seat has no bearing on the attachment method.

The glass panel in your picture is attached to the shower pan by the two metal clips at the bottom. How, exactly, those are attached to the floor isn't evident from the picture, but they're probably either screwed in, held on by double-sided tape (not likely, but possible), or glued down. It is also attached to the wall by one metal clip high up. I would imagine that there is a second clip down low, obscured from view by the corner of the vanity.

There are some glass shower walls that will sit in a metal track instead of having just a few metal clips.

How *your* shower will be attached will be determined 100% by the attachments provided with your shower surround. Drilling holes or applying adhesive will be determined by the installation instructions that come with it. If you don't want to drill holes, then pick a surround that doesn't require that. If you do end up drilling holes, then follow the waterproofing instructions that come with the kit.

If you cannot find a vendor in your town that sells exactly what you're after, you'll either have to find a different vendor in town (maybe look at specialty plumbing houses instead of big-box stores, or look at bath/kitchen/interior design specialty places), or you'll have to leave town to find one in person. As an alternative, you could look on-line at the manufacturer web sites to find one you like. Almost all manufacturers post the installation instructions as a PDF that you can download and look through. If the one you love calls for drilling, either move on or accept that you'll be putting holes in your new shower area.

If you find one you love with an acceptable attachment method, you can purchase it direct from the manufacturer (in most cases) or special order it from an online vendor (they'll link to their authorized vendors if they don't sell direct).